# Is it possible to walk between all three terminals in Dubai Airport without leaving airside?

Tags: dxb, airport-terminals

We are arriving into Terminal 2 on the 28th December and want to go to the business lounge in Terminal 1 before getting a flight from Terminal 3 eight hours later.

Comment: Can you edit your question once more? I think you submitted it before it was finished, now it ends in "bu".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visiting a lounge in T1 at Dubai International Airport, during a layover at T3?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/visiting-a-lounge-in-t1-at-dubai-international-airport-during-a-layover-at-t3)

Comment: Wow, it's *almost* a duplicate, but not exactly. :) That question is about T1 <-> T3. This is about all three terminals. Some answers on the other question would still be useful though.

Comment: Dubai airport is funny, t1 and t3 is only used for check-in, immigration and custom check. Gates, remote stand and lounges is located in ConcourseA,B,C. 3 concourses and t1/3 are directly linked or linked by APM.

Answer (score 18):

From [Wikitravel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubai_International_Airport#Passenger_terminals):

> Dubai Airport currently has three passenger terminals. Terminals 1 and
> 3 are directly connected with a common transit area, with airside
> passengers being able to move freely between the terminals without
> going through immigration, whilst Terminal 2 is built on the opposite
> end of the airport. For transiting passengers, a shuttle service runs
> between the terminals, with a journey time of around 20 minutes from
> Terminal 2 to Terminal 1, and 30 minutes to Terminal 3.

So it appears there is a means to get between the terminals if you're a transiting passenger, but you have to take the bus, not walk.

After the pandemic, there are no more shuttle buses between terminals 3 and 2. There are only taxis, which cost around AED 50.00 as of end of 2023.

Comment: Thanks Mark, so basically we shuttle to T1 then it seems we may be able to walk from T1 to T3

Comment: Yeah that sounds like the best plan.  Make sure to allow yourself enough time to get to your flight!

Comment: The joint T1-T3 terminal is pretty long, from one end to the other takes about 20 minutes!

Comment: I transferred from T2 to T3 yesterday, the process took about an hour gate-to-gate. The transfer minibus is very, very slow, and only runs once every 15 minutes, and it can only take 16 passengers at a time. I had to get to an A gate, which added extra time. Beware!

Answer (score 11):

You should not have any issues traveling between Terminal 1 and 3. As you are arriving at Terminal 2 and have a connecting flight from Terminal 3 you will be put on the transit bus to take you to Terminal 3.

I would like to add a point to @Mark's answer that unless you have a boarding pass for Terminal 3 or 1 (gates A, B or C) you cannot freely move between Terminal 2 and Terminal 1.  The airline has to specifically allow you to go there, because you may need to use public transport and they will ask to see your boarding pass before letting you on the bus.

Terminal 1 and 3 are connected, so you can freely walk around; and to get to gates A (the dedicated A380 gates), you need to take the train.

Answer (score 3):

I arrived at Terminal 2 at night and had a big surprise: there is no bus that takes you to T1 or T3, only a taxi. So be prepared with at least 50-65 AED to pay to the taxi driver that will get you to T1 or T3 metro station.

Everyone says the transfer is available only if you have a ticket to fly to another destination. I was very disappointed about this.

Comment: The bus is for transit, not arrivals. So if you exited Terminal 2, there won't be a bus available.