# Transferring from T3 to T2 in Dubai

Tags: transit, airports, dxb

I arrive at Dubai at terminal 3 and have an onward flight from terminal 2 - Air India express to amritsar .

My arrival time is 07:15 and onward flight leaves at 09:50. Will I and my baggage make this flight? Also what is the procedure on arrival in Dubai ?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to walk between all three terminals in Dubai Airport without leaving airside?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/is-it-possible-to-walk-between-all-three-terminals-in-dubai-airport-without-leav) (has details of the T3/T2 transfer process and timings)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have separate itineraries, because [Terminal 3 is exclusively for Emirates](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/dubai_international_airport/emirates_terminal_3/emirates_terminal_3.aspx) and Qantas, and Terminal 1 is for all other airlines.

Terminal 2 is generally reserved for low cost carriers.

To start off with - there are no visa requirements to transit between the three terminals.

However, as Terminal 3 is exclusively for Emirates - any checked baggage is transferred to Emirates (and possibly Qantas) flights.  The only exception is FlyDubai [which have an agreement with Emirates to transfer checked-in luggage](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/connecting_with_flydubai/connecting_with_flydubai.aspx).

So - to transit between Terminal 2 and Terminal 3 is possible if you are carrying a boarding pass / ticket for your onward journey. Simply follow the transit signs and ask the information desk for transit to Terminal 2 (or, just follow the transit signs for FlyDubai as they also fly out from Terminal 2).

Your baggage is a different story. If its only checked through to Dubai on Emirates; you will need to exit the terminal through immigration; collect your bags and then re-check in at Terminal 2.