# Transit flight Requirement at Dubai Airport

Tags: transit, layovers, dubai, pakistan, flydubai

I want to fly from Iran (IKA) -> Dubai (DXB) -> Islamabad (ISB).
When I search for flights from IKA to ISB the following route doesn't show up. With respect to covid restrictions would it be possible to book these flights separately? Is there enough time in between these two to make it? What if I only take a carry-on with me and no luggage?

1. IKA (1:05) -> DXB (2:45)
2. DXB (05:10) -> ISB (09:00)

Comment: Dubai is DXB not DBX. FlyDubai arrives in terminal 2 while PIA departs from Terminal 3. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/is-it-possible-to-walk-between-all-three-terminals-in-dubai-airport-without-leav (shuttle bus from T2 to T3: 30 minutes, every 15 minutes, limited capacity).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I edited the DXB error. There also seems to be a FlyDubai flight that lands in terminal 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlyDubai flight 1930 arrives in terminal 2. PIA flights depart from terminal 3. Those terminals are literally on opposite sides of the airport.

With checked luggage, it’s completely impossible. You need to:

- disembark
- get to passport control, queue, get through
- wait for your luggage
- exit the terminal and get to the shuttle bus stop
- wait for a shuttle bus (one shuttle every 15 minutes, with limited capacity so you may have to wait for the next one)
- get to terminal 3 (30 minutes)
- get to the check-in desk for your flight, queue, and check in 1 hour before departure

So you have to do all that in 40 minutes, when just the transfer from terminal 2 to to terminal 3 takes between 30 and 45 minutes in the best of cases.

Without luggage, provided you can check-in online (which is not a given, especially these days) you need to:

- disembark
- get to passport control, queue, get through
- exit the terminal and get to the shuttle bus stop
- wait for a shuttle bus (one shuttle every 15 minutes, with limited capacity so you may have to wait for the next one)
- get to terminal 3 (30 minutes)
- go through passport control, security
- get to your gate 30 minutes before departure

So you have 1h10 to do all that. Some people have done it in about an hour, but it’s a very close call, and if you just missed a shuttle, or the shuttle is full and you need to wait for the next one, and you’re toast. It also depends a lot on how long it takes to go through passport control (twice) and security. I have no recent experience with DXB so I have no idea what the wait times usually are and/or if they can vary significantly.

And that’s if your incoming flight is on time.

So I’d say, even without checked luggage, no.

The usual rule of thumb for self-connections is at least 4 hours between arrival and departure, though I would add some additional margin given the requirement to change terminals. COVID-related restrictions and checks also add some time.

Remember that if you miss your outgoing flight after having bought the tickets separately you’re on the hook to book and buy a new ticket (at last minute prices which may be a **lot** more expensive), all incidentals, and any further flights on the same ticket may be cancelled as well. If you book connecting flights all that is the airline’s responsibility.

Comment: So if FZ1930 lands in T2 I am screwed. But I think this particular flight lands in T3. It says so on the flight reservation page on the flydubai website. More over [this](https://www.flydubai.com/en/destinations/flydubai-operations-dxb-terminal-3) says "that All flight numbers for flydubai services operating into and out of Terminal 3, Dubai International (DXB) will have 4 digits and begin with the number 1". So I should be fine as long as they don't change the terminal?

Comment: @esihaj weird, the same page has a list of all flights operating from terminal 3, and that doesn’t include Tehran. Even if you are in the same terminal, with checked luggage you still have to do most of the steps and check-in for the next flight within 40 minutes, which is quite unlikely in my opinion. Without checked luggage, **provided you can check on online** (which is likely not possible due to Covid checks), it may be possible if there aren’t any delays. Still very risky. Why are you so keen on that combination of flights?

Comment: Most other flights have been cancelled and I really need to go there. I am checking all my options and trying to assess if they are realistic ones.