# Luggage Transfer From Karachi to Brunei

Tags: air-travel, luggage, dxb

I am travelling alone with 2 kids from Karachi to Dubai (terminal 3)in emirates and will take Royal Brunei from terminal 1. (double jacket tickets):

Q1. Can i have my luggage transferred or booked for Brunei from Karachi?
Q2. How will i travel from terminal 3 - 1 without a visa?

Comment: At Dubai airport, Terminals 1 and 3 are just different ends of the same building, so you walk between them. There's some info on that in [this question here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/visiting-a-lounge-in-t1-at-dubai-international-airport-during-a-layover-at-t3)

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. On this site and others in the stackexchange network, you should ask one question at a time. You should edit this question to only ask Q1 and make a new question for Q2.

Comment: As for your Q1, this depends on your ticket. What is a double jacket ticket?

Answer (score 2):

If you are issued both boarding passes at Karachi, then your luggage will be checked through  as well.

There are no visa requirements to transit between any terminal at Dubai International. You will simply walk from one end of the terminal to the other; or if you are transiting from Terminal 2, there will be a bus.

- Terminal 3 is dedicated for Emirates.
- Terminal 1 is for all other airlines.
- Terminal 2 is for low cost carriers (mainly FlyDubai but others as well)