# Transfer between Dubai's Terminals 1 and 3, when traveling on separate tickets?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, airport-security, dxb

I am arriving in Dubai terminal 1 on Ethiopian airlines and wish to transfer to Emirates flight at terminal 3, do I need to go through immigration/security? do I need to collect my bags?

Comment: Did you purchase your tickets on a single booking or separate tickets?

Comment: I purchased them online seperate with Ethiopian and Emirates airlines

Comment: Terminals 1 and 3 are physically connected airside, you can just walk between them. You'll have to go through connections security before being let into the airside area. Checked bags may be a bigger issue, depending on if it's 1 or 2 tickets

Comment: Related: [Visiting a lounge in T1 at Dubai International Airport, during a layover at T3?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/visiting-a-lounge-in-t1-at-dubai-international-airport-during-a-layover-at-t3) (covers moving between terminals 1 and 3 airside)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to go through immigration, you can walk between T1 and T3. As for your luggage, it is a different story.

If your luggage is tagged to Dubai, then you will need to either collect it yourself (which requires a visa), or pay for the Marhaba Services and have them collect and re-check it for you on Emirates.

Comment: Burhan many thanks for your answer I have contacted Merhaba to see what they can do.